# Keep iMac awake but the screen off

Tags: sleep, imac, energy-saving

Is there a way to keep iMac awake but let display sleep? Programs like Caffeine and Jiggler will keep the screen on and this is what I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Other than tuning down the brightness to 0, you mean?

Comment: i see! i guess that would work too if i can do it from a script...

Comment: Looks like you can do it: http://www.google.com/search?q=brightness+applescript